# Jira plugin for creating reference books

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Maybe someone here about plugin for Jira for creating reference books?

What I mean? For example I have 3 servers:

- Server_1
- Server_2
- Server_3

And I want to create issue for the admin to give access to Server_1 and Server_2 for User_1 and access to Server_2 and Server_3 for User_2.

Why I need reference books? Because I want to see in one place what users have access to, for example, Server_1.

(In my rea lworld case I have 800 servers with different names and more then 100 users, that can requesting accesses to this servers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JIRA it helps to think how you would do it in a spreadsheet, then convert the idea to JIRA.  So if you have a row per server, would you have a column named "Users"? In that case you would create a new JIRA issue per server and have a custom multi-user picker field in that  issue to record who the users are with access to that server.